# Pimps are not working when used with generics

Tags: scala, generics

Consider following code (script) in which the `SeqPimps` can't be changed:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

implicit class SeqPimps[T: ClassTag](s: Seq[T]) {
  def indexOfOpt(e: T): Option[Int] = s.indexOf(e) match {
    case -1 => None
    case idx => Some(idx)
  }
}

class A[T] {
  val fn = (y: T) => List[T]().indexOfOpt(y)
}

object Main extends App {
  val fn = (y: Int) => List[Int]().indexOfOpt(y)

  println(fn(0))
  println((new A[String]).fn(""))
}
Main.main(args)
```

It crashes with:

```
xxx/test.scala:11: error: value indexOfOpt is not a member of List[T]
  val fn = (y: T) => List[T]().indexOfOpt(y)
                               ^
one error found
```

My questions:

- Why is it working when type is explicitly specified (in `Main`, after commenting out `A` and the one `println` it works fine) and complaining about non-existing member when generic type is used? The call looks same.
- How to fix the snippet without modifying `SeqPimps` (e.g. removing of `ClassTag` - it is required by other methods in real project)?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that writing `class SeqPimps[T: ClassTag](s: Seq[T])` actually tells the compiler to add an implicit parameter like that: `class SeqPimps[T](s: Seq[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T])`.

The compilation fails because the implicit `SeqPimps` cannot be applied, and this one cannot be applied because no implicit `ClassTag[T]` is available from within `A`.

There are a couple ways you can add a `ClassTag` there, for example: `class A[T : ClassTag] {`. Where to pass that implicit `ClassTag` is up to you and your use case...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it turns out I was missing a `ClassTag` in class definition:

```
class A[T: ClassTag] {
```